# macbook pro Version 10.13.6 (17G65)

Tags: wireless-networking, terminal, macbook-pro, data-transfer, process-hacker

I am living with in the same house with an IT man and i think he is hacking my computed and keep all of my data, Please tell me if i ma hacked.

I have got these messages on my terminal,
[Last login: Fri Jul 30 01:57:00 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro:~ Sony$ /macOS\ Install\ Data/brtool ; exit;
WARN: Falling back to old namespace for SecureBoot policy
/.IABlessInfo/BlessInfo.plist open failed
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

as well this message too
Last login: Fri Jul 30 01:29:51 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro:~ Sony$ uptime
1:57  up  1:03, 2 users, load averages: 1.42 1.84 2.14
MacBook-Pro:~ Sony$ Last login: Fri Jul 30 01:57:00 on ttys000
Sony      ttys000                   Fri Jul 30 01:57   still logged in
Sony      ttys000                   Fri Jul 30 01:29 - 01:29  (00:00)
Sony      ttys000                   Fri Jul 30 01:27 - 01:27  (00:00)
Sony      ttys000                   Fri Jul 30 01:18 - 01:18  (00:00)
Sony      ttys000                   Fri Jul 30 00:33 - 00:33  (00:00)
Sony      ttys000                   Fri Jul 30 00:31 - 00:31  (00:00)
Sony      ttys000                   Fri Jul 30 00:31 - 00:31  (00:00)

wtmp begins Tue Jun 30 20:57
MacBook-Pro:~ Sony$ MacBook-Pro:~ Sony$ /macOS\ Install\ Data/brtool ; exit;
-bash: MacBook-Pro:~: command not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

[router identifying itself as it is from germany and we are in london and my location is identified in london](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G0iu.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all CONFRONT THE PERSON YOU THINK IS HACKING YOU. If its not his device, hacking you in any way shape or form is ILLEGAL. Second save your data onto an external hard drive and factory reset everything on your mac. This is the safest way to delete any connections from any past IP's and Modems. AS for the error, it might be him connecting a VPN to your modem.  Third did you at ANY POINT recently allow him admin access to your computer? If so please run this in finder. `Finder> Go > Library (you might have to press Command+shift+>) to see the hidden folder` look for the folder LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons. Anything out of the ordinary either A report here or B delete yourself.

Hope this helps.